# Using matrix to analyze an ODE system $\begin{cases}\dot a_k(t)=2(b_k^2-b_{k-1}^2)\\\dot b_k(t)=b_k(a_{k+1}-a_{k})\end{cases}$ with $b_0(t)=b_n(t)=0$.

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, derivatives, tridiagonal-matrices

> Let $a_k(t), b_k (t) \in \mathbb{R} \ (k = 1, 2, \dots, n)$ satisfy the following differential equations:
> $$\begin{aligned} \frac{d}{dt}a_k(t) &= 2 \left( b_k^2 - b_{k-1}^2 \right) \\ \frac{d}{dt} b_k(t) &= b_k \left( a_{k+1} - a_{k} \right)\end{aligned} \qquad k = 1, 2, \dots , n $$
> where $b_0(t) = b_n(t) = 0$. Consider the $n \times n$ tri-diagonal matrix
> $$L(a,b)=\begin{bmatrix}
>     a_1 & b_1 & 0 & \dots  & 0 &0\\
>     b_1 & a_2 & b_2 & \dots  & 0 &0\\
>     \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots& \vdots \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & a_{n-1} & b_{n-1}\\
>     0 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & b_{n-1} & a_n
> \end{bmatrix}$$
> show that:
>
> 1. The eigenvalues of $L(t) = L(a(t), b(t))$ are independent of $t$.
> 2. $\lim_{t \to \infty}b_k(t) = 0$ for $k=1,2,\dots,n-1$.

---

For P1, Let $L(a,b)=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & b_1 & 0 & \dots  & 0 &0\\
    -b_1 & 0 & b_2 & \dots  & 0 &0\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots& \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 0 & b_{n-1}\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & -b_{n-1} & 0
\end{bmatrix}$, then all above becomes $\frac{dL}{dt}=PL-LP$. Since $L$ exists and is unique, $P$ also exists and is unique. Hence there exists only one $U$ such that $\frac{d}{dt}U(t,s)=P(t)U(t,s),U(s,s)=I$. Since $U(t,s)L(s)U(t,s)^{-1}$ is also the solution to $\frac{dL}{dt}=PL-LP$, we must have $L(t)=U(t,s)L(s)U(t,s)^{-1}$ and P1 is solved.

However now I'm stucking on P2, which is equivalent to prove $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}P=0$ or $L$ tends to be diagonal, in which the solution of ODE tends to be constant, and I don't know how to handle with analyzing matrix ODE.

Any help, hint or solution on Problem 2 would be appreciated!

Comment: Where is that problem coming from? What makes you think that the eigenvalues are time-invariant?

Comment: @KBS This comes from a math contest, so I believe this and a straightforward way is of course bash out all coefficients, but I highly doubt that there's some other weird way here I don't know since there's a problem (2)······

Comment: In all competitions there is clever trick.

Answer (score 2):

These are the equations of motion of the [Toda lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toda_lattice) . It is an integrable classical mechanical system, with a Lax matrix given by $L(a,b)$ as you define. The eigenvalues of a Lax matrix can be shown to be time-independent, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax_pair).

Comment: [Related](http://www.hrl.harvard.edu/analog)